# Как можно посмотреть состояние другого процесса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли как-нибудь внутри Python-программы (процесса) узнать состояние другого процесса по `pid`'у ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, для этого можно воспользоваться библиотекой `psutil`.

Вот пример:

```
import psutil
pid = 2400
process = psutil.Process(pid)
print(process.status())
```